# How to best handle multiple subscriptions to the same observable on the template?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

Let's say I have an observable called 'todoList$'. Using the 'async' operator, I'm able to automatically subscribe/unsubscribe from it. The problem in the code below is that there are two identical subscriptions to the same observable:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(todoList$ | async).length > 0>
  <div *ngFor="let todo of todoList$ | async">
    ...
```

This isn't very DRY, and consequentially, we allocate memory for a subscription that could handled more efficiently.

Because of the syntax in the ngIf condition, I don't believe I can use the 'as' keyword to create a template variable for the observable output. **Instead what works is when I use the RxJs 'share' operator from the component file**:

```
todoList$ = this.store.select(todoList).pipe(tap(x => {console.log('testing')}), share());
//testing
```

Without the share operator, "testing" is printed twice. This leads me to believe the share() operator solves this problem. If it does, not exactly sure why/how? Since this can be a prevalent issue/ code smell, what's the best way of handling multiple subscriptions that are identical within the same template?

*I acknowledge there are a few flavors of a similar question floating on StackOverflow. But none have given me exactly what I'm looking for.*

Comment: your solution is very academic but not very readable, I think Michael D answer is best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule I use the `shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })` operator at the end of every `Observable` inside my template. I also add it to base observables which I use to branch of other observables which are then used in the template.
This will make sure subscriptions are shared among every subscriber, and by using the `shareReplay` you can get the last emitted result as well inside your component by using `take(1)`.

The reason of the `{ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 }` is that if you just use `shareReplay(1)` it can cause leaking subscriptions, regardless if you are using the `async` pipe.

Back to your example, the answer provided by `Michael D` is not bad, and it makes sense to do it that way. However, it does require some logic in the template, which I personally frown upon.

So, as long as you are using `shareReplay`, there is really no downside into using multiple `async` calls in your template, and you can even make them descriptive and re-usable throughout your template by defining them in your component:

```
export class TodoComponent {
  readonly todoList$ = this.store.select(todoList).pipe(
    shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
  );

  readonly hasTodos$ = this.todoList$.pipe(
    map((todos) => todos?.length > 0),
    shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
  );
}
```

You can then keep your template descriptive:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="hasTodos$ | async>
  <div *ngFor="let todo of todoList$ | async">
  <!-- -->
```

<sub>don't forget your `trackBy`!</sub>

---

If you dislike repeating your code, you can even create your custom operator, and use that:

```
export function shareRef<T>() {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => source.pipe(
    shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
  );
}
```

Which changes your observable to:

```
readonly todoList$ = this.store.select(todoList).pipe(
  shareRef()
);
```

Answer (score 3):

> If it does, not exactly sure why/how?

Let's see how `share()` [is defined](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/share.ts#L61):

```js
function shareSubjectFactory() {
  return new Subject<any>();
}

return (source: Observable<T>) => refCount()(multicast(shareSubjectFactory)(source)) as Observable<T>;
```

First of all,

```js
(source: Observable<T>) => refCount()(multicast(shareSubjectFactory)(source))
```

is the same as

```js
(source: Observable<T>) => source.pipe(
  multicast(shareSubjectFactory),
  refCount()
)
```

`multicast` will return a [`ConnectableObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/ConnectableObservable.ts), which is still an `Observable`, but, among other things, it exposes a `connect` method.

```js
// Inside `multicast` operator

const connectable: any = Object.create(source, connectableObservableDescriptor);
connectable.source = source;
connectable.subjectFactory = subjectFactory;

return <ConnectableObservable<R>> connectable;
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/multicast.ts#L50-L54)

Another interesting thing about it is that when **subscribed to**, the subscriber will be added to the `Subject`'s list of subscribers and the main source **will not** be subscribed until `connect` is called:

```js
_subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>) {
  return this.getSubject().subscribe(subscriber);
}

protected getSubject(): Subject<T> {
  const subject = this._subject;
  if (!subject || subject.isStopped) {
    this._subject = this.subjectFactory();
  }
  return this._subject!;
}
```

For example:

```js
const src$ = privateSrc.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('from src')),
  share(),
  tap(() => console.log('from share()')),
)
```

When `src$` is subscribed:

```js
// Subscriber #1
src$.subscribe(/* ... */)
```

the subscriber will be added to the `Subject`'s subscribers list and the source `src$`, will be subscribed. Why? Because `share` also uses `refCount`, which **subscribes** to the source if a new subscriber is registered when there were no previous active subscribers and will **unsubscribe** from the source if there are no more active subscribers.

Let's take a look at another example:

```js
const src$ = (new Observable(s => {
  console.warn('[SOURCE] SUBSCRIBED')

  setTimeout(() => {
    s.next(1);
  }, 1000);
})).pipe(share());

// First subscriber,
// because it's the first one, `refCount` will to its job and the source will be subscribed
// and this subscriber will be added to the `Subject`'s subscribers list
// note that the source sends the data asynchronously
src$.subscribe(/* ... */)

// The second subscriber
// since the source is already subscribed, `refCount` won't subscribe to it again
// instead, this new subscriber will be added to `Subject`'s list
src$.subscribe(/* ... */)
```

After `1s`, the source will send the value `1` and the subject will receive that value and will send it to its registered subscribers.

This is [how `refCount`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/refCount.ts#L72-L81) does its magic:

```js
// When a new subscriber is registered

(<any> connectable)._refCount++;

// `RefCountSubscriber` will make sure that if no more subscribers are left
// the source will be unsubscribed
const refCounter = new RefCountSubscriber(subscriber, connectable);

// Add the subscriber to the `Subject`'s list
const subscription = connectable.subscribe(refCounter);

if (!refCounter.closed) {
  (<any> refCounter).connection = connectable.connect();
}

return subscription;
```

And `ConnectableObservable.connect` is defined [as follows](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/ConnectableObservable.ts#L38-L51):

```js
connect(): Subscription {
  let connection = this._connection;
  
  if (!connection) {
    // If the source wasn't subscribed before

    this._isComplete = false;
    connection = this._connection = new Subscription();
    
    // Subscribing to the source
    // Every notification send by the source will be first received by `Subject`
    connection.add(this.source
      .subscribe(new ConnectableSubscriber(this.getSubject(), this)));
    
    /* ... */
  }
  return connection;
}
```

---

So, if we have a `src$` observable that needs to be subscribed multiple times in the template, we can apply the above mentioned concepts.

However, there is an important aspect that we should be aware of.

If our template looks like this:

```html
<!-- #1 -->
<div *ngIf="src$ | async"></div>

<!-- ... -->

<!-- #2 -->
<div *ngIf="src$ | async"></div>
```

and `src$`:

```js
src$ = store.pipe(select(/* ... */), share())
```

then, if `store` already has the value, it will be retrieved **synchronously**, meaning that when `#1` will be registered, the `store` will be subscribed and will send that value, but notice that at that time `#2` is **not yet** subscribed, so it won't receive anything.

If the `source` is asynchronous, then we should have no problems, since the subscriptions in the template will most likely by **synchronous**.

But, when the source is **synchronous**, you could solve this problem this way:

```js
src$ = store.pipe(
  select(/* ... */),
  subscribeOn(asyncScheduler),
  share()
)
```

`subscribeOn(asyncScheduler)` is *roughly* the same as delaying the subscription of the source with `setTimeout(() => {}, 0)`. But, this allows for `#2` to be subscribed so that when the source is finally subscribed, both subscribers will receive that value.

Comment: instead of the `subscribeOn(asyncScheduler)`, you can mitigate the issue of `#2` not receiving by using `shareReplay`

Comment: @PoulKruijt, totally agree! I thought it was a good use case for `subscribeOn` as well.

Comment: Yep, you've made a nice extended summary of the inner workings of rxjs. I like it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could actually still use the `as` signature in the `*ngIf` directive to have only one active subscription. Try the following

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(todoList$ | async) as todoList">
  <ng-container *ngIf="todoList.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let todo of todoList">
      ...
```

Comment: Yes, this is a viable option. I'm just curious what is the most efficient approach for the aforementioned scenario. Using excessive structural directives can be a bad thing. Will monitor for other options :)

Comment: @Kode_12, I think that the best aproach is use pipe async (better that use shared, but it's only a personal opinion) really you need these "unnecesary" ng-containers because you can not applied two structurals directives in the same tag, but you can use an unique ng-container, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

use `*ngIf` with this type of condition. I hope it will help you.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(todoList$ | async) as todoList">
  <ng-container *ngIf="todoList && todoList != undefined && todoList.length">
    <div *ngFor="let todo of todoList">
      ...
```

Comment: This answer is similar to Michael D's answer. The ngIf condition you provide is too busy with unnecessary conditions fyi

Answer (score 0):

Another option (I think it's more simple)

```
<ng-container *ngIf="todoList$|async as todoList;else loading">
    <div *ngFor="let todo of todoList">
        {{todo}}
    </div>
  <div *ngIf="!todoList.length">Empty</div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading>loading...</ng-template>
```

Another one, using an intermediate object (*)

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{data:todoList$|async} as todoList">
  <div *ngIf="!todoList.data">loading...</div>
    <div *ngFor="let todo of todoList.data">
        {{todo}}
    </div>
  <div *ngIf="!todoList.data.length">Empty</div>
</ng-container>
```

(*) See that the first *ngIf return always true, but under the ng-container we has in todoList.data the data.